# android application always opens default home page when application comes in foreground

Tags: android, background

I have 15-20 activities in my application. I want when user clicks on the icon of my app on the homepage and the app is running in the background, user should always see the default screen. However, as per default android behavior users see the last screen that appeared before the application goes in background.
I also do not want to lose the back feature capability. Is there any way to know if user is navigating in the same application or user has switched to other application and coming back to my app.
I know we can use onpause()  etc for this kind of thing but I have 15 activities and I want to do this change at one place and do not want to lose back button functionality?

Comment: Yahoo I found the solution and I think it should work well. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842272/android-how-to-exit-an-app-when-user-press-the-home-button#tab-top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842272/android-how-to-exit-an-app-when-user-press-the-home-button#tab-top). In this post @Kevin TeslaCoil has mentioned onUserLeaveHint() function. I will override this function and will call finish() in the function so that when user comes back to application, the application will start from the begining and user will see terms and conditions every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the onPause() of each activity you could either write to a shared preference file if it is the current activity running (and possibly save your backwards stack if you are using one to keep multiple backwards), then in each onResume you could switch intent to the main activity, which could then load up the shared data (either the one piece, or populate an ArrayDeque if you have a stack. ArrayDeque as opposed to Stack, because stack is deprecated, as it is based on the deprecated Vector.)

That might be a little messy, but might not be too bad (I would have to try it to really know).

good luck, I hope that helped. If not, I hope someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... There is a problem with onpause override, if I override onpause this will be called if user is navigating inside the application or user presses home button. I want when user clicks on the home screen and comes back to application he should see default terms and condition page. This is legal requirement. When user is pressing back button inside the application then he should get the normal behavior. Currently I have to override onpause, on resume and onbackpressed in order to get this thing done. Is there any simpler approach

Comment: do you need the user to see terms and conditions each time? it is possible to have a End User License Agreement or similar item pop up that requires a users accepting before being allowed to use the application.  http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/adding-eula-to-android-app/  to make it come up every time, simply leave the testing code in that never allows the accept to be saved. then you can just let the user go back to their previous page (as i believe it occurs now?)

Comment: .  Thanks a lot for the prompt response. I have found another approach . I have described it above. Let me know if you think there is any harm in using onUserLeaveHint() method and finish the app so that the user see terms and condition every time user clicks on myapp icon on homepage. I am not worried about the performance by restarting the app because a)I am not doing many things at startup b) this legal thing is more important for the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by adding a boolean and making true whenever the application goes to background. You can use the onPause() for this.

After that you would have to do the checking on each activity using that boolean and the onResume().

I know it's not the prettiest way but i think that this can do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response... however, I want when user clicks on home button and comes back to my app, he should see terms and condition page every time. On pause and onresume can do that but then I lose back feature of the application. Currently I am overriding onpause on resume and on back pressed. I would be really glad if there is a simpler approach to achieve this.