# Killing an Android App with the Home Key

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an android app, and when the Home key is pressed I want it to terminate. Period. I dont want it hanging around running in the background. I just want it terminated. What's the best or prferred method to do this?

Comment: Try **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842272/android-how-to-exit-an-app-when-user-press-the-home-button)**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*No you don't.*

- Trying to "kill" your app is an Android antipattern.
- Trying to catch the home key is *also* an Android antipattern.

There is a vast amount of material substantiating these points.  If you think you do want your application killed, you're just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish();` to terminate an activity.

Comment: But not if you're deep in the Activity stack, you would have to call it an appropriate number of times to get back to the "start" of the app.